# Cannot give aws-lambda access to aws-appsync API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I am working on a project where users can upload files into a S3 bucket, these uploaded files are mapped to a GraphQL key (which was generated by Amplify CLI), and an aws-lambda function is triggered. All of this is working, but the next step I want is for this aws-lambda function to create a second file with the same ownership attributes and POST the location of the saved second file to the GraphQL API.

I figured that this shouldn't be too difficult but I am having a lot of difficulty and can't understand where the problem lies.

**BACKGROUND/DETAILS**

I want the owner of the data (the uploader) to be the only *user* who is able to access the data, with the aws-lambda function operating in an *admin* role and able to POST/GET to API of any owner.

The GraphQL schema looks like this:

```
type FileUpload @model 
@auth(rules: [
  { allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  foo: String
  bar: String
}
```

And I also found this seemingly-promising AWS guide which I thought would give an IAM role *admin* access (https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#configure-custom-identity-and-group-claims) which I followed by creating the file `amplify/backend/api/<your-api-name>/custom-roles.json` and saved it with

```
{
  "adminRoleNames": ["<YOUR_IAM_ROLE_NAME>"]
}
```

I replaced "<YOUR_IAM_ROLE_NAME>" with an IAM Role which I have given broad access to, including this appsync access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appsync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is the role given to my aws-lambda function.

When I attempt to run a simple API query in my aws-lambda function with the above settings I get this error

```
response string:  
{
    "data": {
        "getFileUpload": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "getFileUpload"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": "Unauthorized",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 11,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "Not Authorized to access getFileUpload on type Query"
        }
    ]
}
```

my actual python lambda script is

```
import http
API_URL = '<MY_API_URL>'
API_KEY = '<>MY_API_KEY'
HOST = API_URL.replace('https://','').replace('/graphql','')

def queryAPI():
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(HOST, 443)
    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/graphql', 
        'x-api-key': API_KEY,
        'host': HOST
    }

    print('conn: ', conn)
    
    query = '''
            {
          getFileUpload(id: "<ID_HERE>") {
            description
            createdAt
            baseFilePath
          }
        }
    '''
    graphql_query = {
        'query': query
    }
    query_data = json.dumps(graphql_query)
    print('query data: ', query_data)
    conn.request('POST', '/graphql', query_data, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    response_string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    print('response string: ', response_string)
```

I pass in the API key and API URL above in addition to giving AWS-lambda the IAM role. I understand that only one is probably needed, but I am trying to get the process to work then pare it back.

**QUESTION(s)**

As far as I understand, I am

1. providing the appropriate @auth rules to my GraphQL schema based on my goals and (2 below)
2. giving my aws-lambda function sufficient IAM authorization (via both IAM role and API key) to override any potential restrictive @auth rules of my GraphQL schema

But clearly something is not working. Can anyone point me towards a problem that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem just yesterday.
It was not 1:1 what you're trying to do, but maybe it's still helpful.

So I was trying to give lambda functions permissions to access the data based on my graphql schema. The schema had different @auth directives, which caused the lambda functions to not have access to the data anymore. Even though I gave them permissions via the cli and IAM roles. Although the documentation says this should work, it didn't:

> if you grant a Lambda function in your Amplify project access to the GraphQL API via amplify update function, then the Lambda function's IAM execution role is allow-listed to honor the permissions granted on the Query, Mutation, and Subscription types.
> Therefore, these functions have special access privileges that are scoped based on their IAM policy instead of any particular @auth rule.

So I ended up adding `@auth(rules: [{ allow: custom }])` to all parts of my schema that I want to access via lambda functions.

When doing this, make sure to add "lambda" as auth mode to your api via `amplify update api`.

In the authentication lambda function, you could then check if the user, who is invoking the function, has access to the requested query/S3 Data.